# "No appropriate default constructor" I have looked everywhere for an answer

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

I have looked at everyone of the posts about this topic and none are helpful. PLEASE help my assignment is due in two hours.

Here is the relevant header

```
    class RCB {
private:
    str                 rID;
    int                 numResources;
    int                 availableResources;
    int                 resourcesRequested;     //The amount of resources requested including resources requested from PCB's in the waitlist


public:

    std::list<PCB*>     waitList;

    RCB(str name, int r);
    ~RCB();

    void setRID(str name) { rID = name; }
    void allocateResources(int n) { availableResources -= n; }
    void returnResources(int n) { availableResources += n; }

    int getNumResources(){ return numResources; }
    int getAvailableResources(){ return availableResources; }
    str getRID(){ return rID; }
    int getResourcesRequested() { return resourcesRequested; }

};
```

And here is the source file

```
  RCB::RCB(str name, int r) :
        rID{ name },
        numResources{ r },
        availableResources{ r },
        resourcesRequested{ 0 }
    {}
```

I get the error

Error   1   error C2512: 'RCB' : no appropriate default constructor available   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\tuple    746 1   ProcessScheduler

Here is the rest of the source

```
#include "Data.h"



PCB::PCB(str name, int p) : 
    pID{ name },
    status{ READY },
    backptr{ nullptr },
    parent{ nullptr },
    priority{ p }
{

    //Insert resource counters into the resource log
    resourceLog.insert(std::pair<str, int>("R1", 0));
    resourceLog.insert(std::pair<str, int>("R2", 0));
    resourceLog.insert(std::pair<str, int>("R3", 0));
    resourceLog.insert(std::pair<str, int>("R4", 0));


    //Insert resource request counters into the request log
    requestBackLog.insert(std::pair<str, int>("R1", 0));
    requestBackLog.insert(std::pair<str, int>("R2", 0));
    requestBackLog.insert(std::pair<str, int>("R3", 0));
    requestBackLog.insert(std::pair<str, int>("R4", 0));
}


PCB::~PCB()
{




}

//Print the proccess ID to stdout
void PCB::printID()
{

    std::cout << pID << " ";

}








RCB::RCB(str name, int r) :
    rID{ name },
    numResources{ r },
    availableResources{ r },
    resourcesRequested{ 0 }
{}


RCB::RCB(const RCB& r)
{
    rID = r.rID;
    numResources = r.numResources;
    availableResources = r.availableResources;
    resourcesRequested = r.resourcesRequested;

}

RCB::RCB() :
    rID{ "R0" },
    numResources{ 5 },
    availableResources{ 5 },
    resourcesRequested{ 0 }
{

}


MainProcess::MainProcess() :
    initProcess("init", 0),
    currentlyRunning{ &initProcess }

{

    //Add init to the list of process names
    nameList.push_back("init");

    RCB R1("R1", 1);
    RCB R2("R2", 2);
    RCB R3("R3", 3);
    RCB R4("R4", 4);


    //Initialize four resources in the resource map
    resourceMap.insert(std::pair<str, RCB>("R1", R1));
    resourceMap.insert(std::pair<str, RCB>("R2", R2));
    resourceMap.insert(std::pair<str, RCB>("R3", R3));
    resourceMap.insert(std::pair<str, RCB>("R4", R4));


    //Add a reference to the initial process to lowest list on the ready list 
    readyList[0].push_back(&initProcess);
    initProcess.setStatus(RUNNING);

    //Print the id of the init process to stdout
    initProcess.printID();







}

void MainProcess::Release(str rID, int num)
{

    //Check for negative numbers
    if (num < 0){
        std::cout << "error ";
        return;
    }


    //Subtract resources from the resource log of the currently running process
    currentlyRunning->resourceLog[rID] = std::max(currentlyRunning->resourceLog[rID] - num, 0);

    //Add resources back to the available resources
    resourceMap[rID].returnResources(num);

    //Iterator pointing to the first PCB in the waitlist
    std::list<PCB*>::iterator it = resourceMap[rID].waitList.begin();

    //CONDITION
    //The waitlist on the RCB is not empty AND 
    //the amount of available resources in the RCB is greater than the amount of
    //requested resources by the PCB at the front of the waitlist
    while (!resourceMap[rID].waitList.empty() && resourceMap[rID].getAvailableResources() > 0 && it != resourceMap[rID].waitList.end())
    {

        if ((*it)->requestBackLog[rID] <= resourceMap[rID].getAvailableResources() ){

            //Allocate backloged resources from the RCB
            resourceMap[rID].allocateResources((*it)->requestBackLog[rID]);

            //Give the allocated resources to the PCB
            (*it)->resourceLog[rID] += (*it)->requestBackLog[rID];

            //Zero out the request back log
            (*it)->requestBackLog[rID] = 0;


            //Change the status of the PCB and add it to the ready list         
            (*it)->setStatus(READY);
            (*it)->setBackPtr(readyList);
            readyList[(*it)->getPriority()].push_back((*it));

            //Move the iterator to the next element in the wait list
            it++;

            //Remove the PCB from the waitlist
            resourceMap[rID].waitList.pop_front();


            //Call the scheduler
            Scheduler();


        }


        //If the PCB at the front of the wait list is asking for too many resources
        //then just skip it and move on to the next PCB on the waitlist
        else
        {
            it++;
        }



    }



}

void MainProcess::FreeResources(PCB* p)
{

    //Free all the resources currently held by PCB p
    for (auto& item : p->resourceLog){
        Release(item.first, item.second);
    }


}

void MainProcess::Destroy(str PID)
{

    //Search the ready list for the PCB with the specified PID
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++){
        for (PCB* p : readyList[i]){
            if (p->getPID() == PID){
                KillTree(p);
                Scheduler();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    //If no PCB was found with PID then output error
    std::cout << "error ";



}

void MainProcess::KillTree(PCB* p)
{
    //Recursively call kill tree on each child
    if (!p->children.empty()){
        for (PCB* child : p->children)
        {
            KillTree(child);

        }

    }

    //If the PCB has no children then free all of its resources and delete it.
    FreeResources(p);
    delete p;
    return;


}

void MainProcess::Create(str name, int p)
{

    std::vector<str>::iterator it = std::find(nameList.begin(), nameList.end(), name);

    if (it != nameList.end()){
        std::cout << "error ";
        return;
    }

    else{

        //Add the new process name to the list of process names
        nameList.push_back(name);

        //Create a reference to a new process
        PCB* newProcess = new PCB(name, p);

        //Set the back pointer to the ready list
        newProcess->setBackPtr(readyList);

        //Set the parent pointer to the parent process
        newProcess->setParent(currentlyRunning);

        //Add it to the process tree
        currentlyRunning->children.push_back(newProcess);

        //Add the new process to the ready list
        newProcess->setStatus(READY);
        readyList[newProcess->getPriority()].push_back(newProcess);

        //Call the scheduler
        Scheduler();

    }



}



void MainProcess::Request(str rID, int num)
{
    RCB* rcb;

    //Check for negative numbers
    if (num < 0){
        std::cout << "error ";
        return;
    }

    //rcb is a reference to a resource in the resource map
    rcb = &resourceMap[rID];

    //If resources are available
    if (rcb->getAvailableResources() >= num){
        rcb->allocateResources(num);

        //Give the requested resources to the running process
        currentlyRunning->resourceLog[rID] += num;




        //Insert RCB into resource list of currently running process if not in there already
        std::list<RCB*>::iterator it = std::find(currentlyRunning->other_Resources.begin(), currentlyRunning->other_Resources.end(), rcb);

        if (it == currentlyRunning->other_Resources.end()){

            currentlyRunning->other_Resources.push_back(rcb);

        }
    }



    else
    {

        //Stop the process from running and put it on the blocked list
        currentlyRunning->setStatus(BLOCKED);
        currentlyRunning->setBackPtr(&rcb->waitList);

        readyList[currentlyRunning->getPriority()].pop_front();
        rcb->waitList.push_back(currentlyRunning);

        //Log the requested amount in the request back log
        currentlyRunning->requestBackLog[rID] += num;

        //Call Scheduler
        Scheduler();


    }

}


void MainProcess::Scheduler()
{

    PCB* p = getHighestPriority();

    if (currentlyRunning != p){

        //Set the currently running process to the 
        currentlyRunning = p;

        //Set the status of the currently running process to "RUNNING"
        currentlyRunning->setStatus(RUNNING);
    }

    //Print the id of the currently running process
    currentlyRunning->printID();

}

void MainProcess::TimeOut()
{


    //Remove currently running process from the front of the list and put it in the back
    readyList[currentlyRunning->getPriority()].pop_front();
    currentlyRunning->setStatus(READY);
    readyList[currentlyRunning->getPriority()].push_back(currentlyRunning);

    Scheduler();

}

PCB* MainProcess::getHighestPriority()
{
    //Iterate through the ready list to find the highest priority process
    for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--){
        if (!readyList[i].empty()){
            return readyList[i].front();
        }
    }

    //Return null if no process is found
    return nullptr;
}

void MainProcess::Reset()
{

    for (PCB* p : initProcess.children){

        KillTree(p);

    }

    Scheduler();


}
```

I'm pretty sure this is where the problem is

```
//Add init to the list of process names
    nameList.push_back("init");

    RCB R1("R1", 1);
    RCB R2("R2", 2);
    RCB R3("R3", 3);
    RCB R4("R4", 4);


    //Initialize four resources in the resource map
    resourceMap.insert(std::pair<str, RCB>("R1", R1));
    resourceMap.insert(std::pair<str, RCB>("R2", R2));
    resourceMap.insert(std::pair<str, RCB>("R3", R3));
    resourceMap.insert(std::pair<str, RCB>("R4", R4));
```

Comment: str is a typedef for std::string

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With the posted code, it is hard telling what could be wrong.

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant but why are you using curl brackets in your initializer list for your constructor. e.g. change each of these `: rID{ name }, ...` to this `: rID(name), ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No appropriate default constructor available" error in Visual C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710432/no-appropriate-default-constructor-available-error-in-visual-c)

Answer (score 1):

When you define a parameterized constructor [RCB(str name, int r)], the compiler will NOT generate the default no arguments constructor. So in your case, if you try to create an object of RCB [RCB obj;], it is bound to throw this error. To solve, you need to define a default no args constructor. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: If you posted something, you should find the edit button at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, the class RCB has no default constructor. This is fine. Not all classes have to have a default constructor. However, something in your code, which is using RCB (not part of what you included in the question) is trying to invoke the default constructor of RCB, either explicitly or implicitly.

For instance, if you declare somewhere in your code

```
RCB rcb;
```

Then you're using a default constructor.